# :first-child with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-repeat, css-selectors

I have an ng-repeat and only want to apply a style to the first `div` with the class `type` in the ng-repeat.

```
<div class="my-list" ng-repeat="item in list">
  <div class="type">
    <span>{{item.label}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="check">
    <span>{{item.ischecked}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following but it applied the CSS to all the `divs` with a class of `type`

```
.my-list .type:first-child
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `$first`, that indicates the first iteration within a `ng-repeat`.

```
<div class="my-list" ng-repeat="item in list">
  <div class="type" ng-class="{myClass:$first}">
    <span>{{item.label}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="check">
    <span>{{item.ischecked}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @dmo It appears that the pseudo class is being applied to the commented-out code, which is the first in the iteration.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you need to do the other way around.

```
.my-list:first-child .type{
  color:red;
}
```

`ng-repeat` will put multiple `.my-list` divs and you want to target the `.type` of the first div alone. So apply selector on `.my-list`.